# Using awk to try to find a variable in a CSV line

Tags: bash, csv, variables, awk

I am trying to go through two files. First one line by line, while using awk to search for a line containing a string pulled from the first file.

```
while IFS=, read col1 col2 col3
do
    echo $(awk -F, -v var="$col2" '$2==var || $2=="www."var {print $0}' searchFile.csv)
    //do stuff with data from awk
done < origFile.csv
```

I am trying to find domain names in this file, and the awk currently is never returning matches. I have checked the files manually to make sure some that are not returning matches are in both, and they are.

I have tried using a nested loop, but bash was not wanting to open a second file to read and would not read the second file. I also tried using grep, but the files are too large and grep would run out of memory.

Sample input for searchFile.csv:

```
4915,google.com,oct
3532,domain.ca,nov
33451,yahoo.ca,nov
```

I have ensured there are no spaces in the data being input, and have verified that $col2 from origFile.csv matches data in the searchFile.csv

Comment: You should post a line or two that is being matched from the file you are parsing.

Comment: Please post sample input and sample output..

Comment: I updated input, there is no output from the code as is.

Comment: Despite me not liking the style of your code, I don't see any errors in it.  Why are you doing an echo to something that goes to STDOUT?  Regardless, do a `file searchFile.csv` and maybe one on the origFile.csv too.  Verify they are ascii only files, no strange characters.

Comment: @BreannaWilson we're obviously not asking to see the output from a tool that doesn't exist yet, we're asking you to post the **desired** output that you want to get from such a tool once it does exist. Also post the contents of `origFile.csv` so we have concise, testable sample input and the expected output given that input. See [ask] if that's not clear.

Comment: How big is `origFile.csv`?

Answer (score -2):

Does your data file have spaces?  If so, your records ($2) will have spaces and may not match (because you are using awk -F,).  Try matching with ~ instead of == .

Comment: There are no spaces in the source data, and it is delimited with commas.

Comment: @Justin, use comments to ask questions, instead of Answers :-)